# Unable to upload to azure media service

Tags: c#, azure, azure-media-services

I have been trying to upload a file to Azure media server but i am getting the excpetion as

**Azure Media Services endpoint Uri schema is not valid**

I have tried below code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
             .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
             .Build();
    //_cachedCredentials = new MediaServicesCredentials(_mediaServicesAccountName,
    //_mediaServicesAccountKey);
    //_context = new CloudMediaContext(_cachedCredentials);

    Program program = new Program(configuration);

    //var tokenCredentials1 = new AzureAdTokenCredentials(program._mediaServicesTenant, AzureEnvironments.AzureCloudEnvironment);
    //var tokenProvider1 = new AzureAdTokenProvider(tokenCredentials1);
    //var mediaContext = new CloudMediaContext(new Uri(program._mediaServicesURL), tokenProvider1);
    //mediaContext.Assets.FirstOrDefault();


    AzureAdTokenCredentials tokenCredentials =
               new AzureAdTokenCredentials(program._mediaServicesTenant,
                   new AzureAdClientSymmetricKey(program._mediaServicesClientID, program._mediaServicesClientSecret),
                   AzureEnvironments.AzureCloudEnvironment);

    var tokenProvider = new AzureAdTokenProvider(tokenCredentials);

    //program._mediaServicesURL is "https://management.azure.com/"
    _context = new CloudMediaContext(new Uri(program._mediaServicesURL), tokenProvider);



    IAsset inputAsset = CreateAssetAndUploadSingleFile(@"E:\User\SampleVideo.mp4", AssetCreationOptions.CommonEncryptionProtected);

    //EncodeToAdaptiveBitrateMP4Set(inputAsset);
}
 

 static public IAsset CreateAssetAndUploadSingleFile(string singleFilePath, AssetCreationOptions assetCreationOptions)
{
    if (!File.Exists(singleFilePath))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File does not exist.");
        return null;
    }

    var assetName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(singleFilePath);
    //create a new input asset
    IAsset inputAsset = _context.Assets.Create(assetName, assetCreationOptions);

    var assetFile = inputAsset.AssetFiles.Create(Path.GetFileName(singleFilePath));

    Console.WriteLine("Created assetFile {0}", assetFile.Name);

    //create a 30-day read and list access policy
    var policy = _context.AccessPolicies.Create(
    assetName,
    TimeSpan.FromDays(30),
    AccessPermissions.Read | AccessPermissions.List);

    //create a SAS locator to display the asset
    var locator = _context.Locators.CreateLocator(LocatorType.Sas, inputAsset, policy);

    Console.WriteLine("Upload {0}", assetFile.Name);

    assetFile.Upload(singleFilePath);

    Console.WriteLine("Done uploading {0}", assetFile.Name);

    locator.Delete();
    policy.Delete();

    return inputAsset;
}
```

**Please Help me out i have seen lot of articles but no luck can anyone provide the complete upload working code if possible**

Comment: It's telling you that the URL is wrong. How did you come to have the management URL there and not the media services URL? If you check the Azure Portal you should find the correct URL for your media service.

Comment: Ok may i know where i can get the exact URL i am new to this media services @fredrik

Comment: Normally there's a "Connect" option in the Azure Portal that shows the URL or hostname. But I've never used this service before. You have to check the documentation.

Comment: Ok thanks for the information i am trying to understand the document but it is bit confusing cause there are two versions of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using the old legacy deprecated v2 API.  Was that intentional or a mistake?  If a mistake how did you arrive there?

Can you try to use the latest v3 API from the samples here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/samples-overview

Comment: I need to use the V3 but lot of articles were made me confused i have seen that provided link but i am not sure which one to use for uploading a file to media server

Comment: Yes it looks like there is a lot of v2 content and samples out there still. We will be gradually removing those, as v2 retires on Feb 29, 2024.

Comment: For the right sample, start with the .NET basic encoding samples, or the basic streaming ones.  
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-dotnet/tree/main/VideoEncoding/Encoding_H264